# (Bash Script) How to use the same directory for multiple options?

Tags: bash, scripting, getopts

I am confused how to read in multiple options using `getopts` and how to use one directory as the source for both options.  Let me be more specific...

If I were to say:

```
./rpsm.sh -u -g /some/directory
```

or

```
./rpsm.sh -ug /some/directory
```

How would I use `/some/directory` as the directory for both options `-u` and `-g`?

---

Also, how would I list the results of `-u` then list the results of `-g` (or vice versa) after running the script?

Comment: The second part of your question has nothing to do with `getopts`, and is entirely dependent on how you implement `./rpsm.sh`.

Comment: For each parameter if it is not given but the other is, have it default to the other parameter. You'd need to implement this behavior yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a third option (`-B` for both?) to be used to set both `-u` and `-g` simultaneously.

```
while getopts "u:g:B:" opt; do
    case $opt in
      u) u_dir=$OPTARG ;;
      g) g_dir=$OPTARG ;;
      B) u_dir=$OPTARG
         g_dir=$OPTARG
         ;;
    esac
done
```

`getopts` doesn't provide for the type of shortcut you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll use a third option!